# what does it mean of “Life is that perfect fine line between ironies.“?

Tags: quotes, confusables

Life is that perfect fine line between ironies.
~Serj Tankian
https://www.azquotes.com/quote/290519?ref=fine-lines

I can't understand what it means.
Does it mean life is paradox, ironic or ridiculous?

Comment: It means that the speaker's interest in life is its ironies, and nothing else matters. Or that life is perfect until disturbed by its ironies. Or that life is about steering clear of its ironies. It's a quip to which one replies, "Oh, so true."

Comment: Without a context (what comes before that sentence and/or what follows it) the quotation's meaning is opaque.  It could be just one of those attempts to look clever.  I searched for more context without success.  Sorry.

Comment: It's difficult to pin down the sense of irony intended, situational or cosmic. If situational, it reads 'Life is carefully following that perfect fine line so as to avoid ironies (essentially major errors of judgement).' If cosmic, 'Life is when an individual somehow treads the perfect fine line between disasters on every side.' If both, both.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - Or indeed that there is a line that we follow from one irony to the next.

Comment: Chen David - As @Tuffy Indicates, we need context.  Was this said in an interview? If so what was said before? Does this come from a book - if so what was the subject of discussion?  The quote on its own has no obvious meaning.

Comment: I found the context. See my 'answer'. Tuffy may have nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

Just some context, in case it's helpful.

[Serge Tankian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serj_Tankian) is a Lebanon-born, LA-based singer-songwriter. The quotation is from this [interview](https://www.ign.com/articles/2010/09/27/the-imperfect-harmony-of-serj-tankian) with IGN Entertainment, Inc.

IGN: it seems like you're making a statement about social commentary and social media, and everybody is like, "Well isn't that ironic that you would also then use social media..."

Tankian: Personal commentary and social media?

IGN: Right.

Tankian: Of course, of course. Life is that perfect fine line between ironies. No, I am, definitely. But I'm not "LOL"-ing "I just had a burrito." I'm letting you know about a record. Something that I've worked on over the past year. In fact, that's something that I don't use Twitter for is personal, "Hey, I'm having coffee and I met this dude" or whatever. I only speak when I have something to say.

Comment: I had to UV just for the good laugh.

Comment: Ah. It seems that 'ironic' is a euphemism for 'hypocritical' here. Tankian has a point; eat and drink with tax collectors and 'sinners' (the riff-raff?) and you're a wine-bibber and glutton. Lead an abstemious life, and you're crazy (or worse). Isn't there even a fine line?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Spot on, or at least arguably inconsistent.  It seems he uses the very social media he criticises in his songs.  There is a reasonable defence of this from the charge of hypocrisy, which is common enough in many spheres of public life.  Tankian's riposte is a facile but clever off the cuff move, because it sounds profound but cannot, without boring the audience, be countered.

Answer (score 0):

Among the definitions of *irony* is:

> irony = a situation in which something which was intended to have a particular result has the opposite or a very different result
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/irony)

For example, consider only a couple of aspects of the United Kingdom's Brexit:

On irony is that many in the fishing industry believed Brexit to be beneficial to them by increasing their share of catch in British water; after Brexit, exports of British seafood to Europe are now dropping and the fishermen are vigorously complaining about spoilt markets. A second irony is that those who argued that Brexit would allow us to "take back control", now have to face an uncontrollable increase in separatist sentiment in the United Kingdom.

And so it is that the life of politicians in the UK consists of finding a political, social and economic  course (a fine line) between these and other ironies as they try to justify themselves and survive. For the few who manage to do this over a long period, the fine line will be "perfect".